# Cannot Load Deedle in FSharp

Tags: f#, deedle

I have the most basic of question that should be easy but proving to be a pain.  I have a f# FSX file and would like to include Deedle.

I ran the install package and it put it in C:\Users\myName.nuget\packages

Under this directory, the deedle.fsx is in deedle\2.0.4

Now, some of the documentation I have read instructs to do this at the top of the FSX file:
"#I "../../packages/Deedle"
"#load "Deedle.fsx"

Issue#1.  That relative path for #I does not work, so I use an explicit path.  That resolves that issue.

Issue#2. I cannot get the load statement to find the deedle.fsx file.  It appends a bin/net45 to the path.

Therefore, the question is is there a trick I am missing in using this library and how I am referencing it for use?

Thx,
Marc.

Comment: How did you install the Deedle nuget package?

Answer (score 1):

try this in your `fsx` file

```
#r @"C:\Users\myName\.nuget\packages\deedle\2.0.4\lib\net45\deedle.dll"
```

change `myName` to your username.